# How to remove part of a path in Kotlin on Android? (android.graphics)

Tags: android, kotlin

I followed [this Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-canvas#8) for drawing on canvas objects, but now i am stuck on finding a way to erase specific parts path that makes up the drawing.

Is there a way to find the paths of a path intiersecting with a circle for example and then removing the intersection from the path?

I have the paths that were created from different touches saved in a List which i loop through to display:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        // Draw any current squiggle
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

        // Draw the drawing so far
        for(mPath: Path in mDrawing){
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint)
        }
    }
```

For clarity: [this](https://pastebin.com/dHhhMJ9n) contains the whole class